# Rust Analyzer doesnt work after add new cargo

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

So i just add using " cargo new adder --lib " and now my rust analyzer doesnt work and show this massage

> Failed to load workspaces.`rust-analyzer.linkedProjects` have been specified, which may be incorrect. Specified project paths:
>
> ```
> .\shrek\adder\Cargo.toml
> ```

and in output

> 2024-03-25T10:18:55.217855Z ERROR rust_analyzer::main_loop: FetchWorkspaceError:
> rust-analyzer failed to load workspace: Failed to load the project at C:\Users\mufti\OneDrive\Desktop\coding\Rust.\shrek\adder\Cargo.toml: Failed to query rust toolchain version at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\coding\Rust.\shrek\adder, is your toolchain setup correctly?: "C:\Users\user\.cargo\bin\cargo.exe" "--version" failed: The directory name is invalid. (os error 267)

Comment: Please include your folder structure, Cargo.toml, and rust-analyzer settings applies to workspace.

Comment: *"Failed to load the project at ...\Rust.\shrek\adder\..."* - is the directory "Rust." (with a period) correct?